# Jsp session & Rediretion

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets, redirect

I am new in jsp. I am trying to do redirection to login page when expire the session.

My code:

```
String sessionUser = null;
sessionUser = session.getAttribute("UserName").toString();
if(sessionUser == "" || sessionUser == null)
{
    System.out.println("In login");
    response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("out login");
}
```

in above code i get error in line of

```
sessionUser = session.getAttribute("UserName").toString();
```

Error

```
HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 2):

From the error message and your description it seems you have written this code in JSP :

```
sessionUser = session.getAttribute("UserName").toString();
```

The above line can throw error if `session` is `null` or `session` doesn't have a `UserName` attribute .It is bad practice to write scriptlets in JSP.

You need to use a [Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) to do anything closer to what you intend to do :

```
// Do not create session if it doesn't exist
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
// check if session is null
if(session != null) {
     chain.doFilter(request, response);
} else {
     // redirect to login page
     response.sendRedirect("/login.jsp");
}
```

You can implement [HttpSessionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) to listen to the session invalidation event. But a *Listener* is not a good choice here , because it is not tied to a request.

Comment: `!session.isNew()` isn't needed any more since you're already calling `getSession()` with false. The answer's correct though.